# Riemann Integral Confusion

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

"Let $f(x) = 2x$ for $x \in [a,b]$, $a,b \in R^+$, $a<b$. Use the definition of Riemann Integral to show that f is integrable"

---

I know that a bounded function $f \to \mathbb{R}$ is called Riemann Integrable if its upper and lower integrals are equal. I'm not understanding how to calculate $U(f)$ and $L(f)$. In particular, I am not understanding how to calculate $M_k = \sup_{I_k} f(x)$ where $P = {I_1, I_2, \cdots, I_n}$ is a partition of $I$.

EDIT: The question is now
if we can find a sequence P_1,P_2,... of partitions, such that $U_{f,P_k}$ and $L_{f,P_k}$ both converge to the same thing, it will show that this value is both U_f and L_f. BUT I don't know how to do that

Comment: The function is strictly increasing and continuous, so the inf of each sub-interval of the partition is the image of the left endpoint of each sub-interval and similarly the sup is the image of the right endpoint.

Comment: so $U[f; P]$, the upper reimann sum, is $\sum_{i=1}^{n}2x_i (x_i - x_{i-1})$. The lower riemann sum is $L[f; P] = \sum_{i=1}^{n}2(x_{i-1})(x_i - x_{i-1})$. How though do I calculate U(f) and L(f) ? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux_integral

Comment: if we can find a sequence P_1,P_2,... of partitions, such that U_{f,P_k} and L_{f,P_k} both converge to the same thing, it will show that this value is both U_f and L_f. BUT I don't know how to do that @PaulMalinowski

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given, choose $n$ such that $n\cdot \epsilon > 2\cdot \left(b - a\right)^2$, and let partition $P = \{x_0 = a, x_1, x_2,..., x_n = b\}$ where $x_i= a + \left(\dfrac{b-a}{n}\right)\cdot i$ for $i = \overline{0,n}$. Then:
$ U(f) - L(f) = \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n \left(M_i - m_i\right)\cdot (x_i - x_{i-1}) = \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n \left(2x_i - 2x_{i-1}\right)\cdot (x_i - x_{i-1}) = \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n 2\cdot (x_i - x_{i-1})^2 = \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n 2\cdot \left(\dfrac{b-a}{n}\right)^2 = 2n\cdot \dfrac{(b - a)^2}{n^2} = \dfrac{2\cdot (b - a)^2}{n} < \epsilon$.
So $f(x) = 2x$ is integrable on $[a, b]$.

Comment: @Ozera To evaluate the integral, tag $P$ by the midpoints of the subintervals.

Comment: @TonyPiccolo I ended working out a solution of my own that differs from this one! It's less clean, but it is still standard.